# Changing connection timeout value of Apache Jetty in aem not getting applied

Tags: curl, aem, apache-felix

I am using curl to build an AEM package. I am changing the connection timeout value of Apache felix jetty http service in system/console by creating a new instance of it in configuration manager but the change in value is not affecting the POST request. It seems that the changes are not getting applied. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How big is the package?

Comment: Package is of 37MB.